# Red5-Screenshare screen frames blurred when screenshare application is converted to applet

Tags: java, red5, japplet

I have converted Red5-Screenshare application (found on the link below) into a JApplet;

https://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/

I just extended the ScreenShare.java class from JApplet. Then I removed main() method and placed following applet init() method in the ScreenShare.java class.

```
public  void init()
{
    instance = new ScreenShare();


    instance.host = getParameter("host");
    instance.app = getParameter("app");
    instance.port =  Integer.parseInt(getParameter("port"));
    instance.publishName = getParameter("stream");
    instance.codec = getParameter("codec");

    try {
        instance.frameRate = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("framerate"));
        instance.maxWidth = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("width"));
        instance.maxHeight = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("height"));
        logger.debug(instance.maxWidth +","+instance.maxHeight);

    } catch (Exception e) {logger.debug(e.getMessage());}

    System.out.println("User home " + System.getProperty("user.home"));
    System.out.println("User Dir " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));


    logger.debug("host: " + instance.host + ", app: " + instance.app + ", port: " + instance.port + ", publish: " + instance.publishName);

    instance.createWindow();
}
```

This is how the JNLP file for this applet looks like

```xml
<jnlp href="screenshare_applet.jar">
    <information>
        <title>Red5 ScreenShare</title> 
        <vendor>Dele Olajide</vendor> 
        <homepage>http://code.google.com/p/red5screnshare/</homepage>
        <description>Red5 ScreenShare</description> 
        <description kind='short'>An Open Source Screen Share Java application for Adobe Flash using Red5</description> 
        <offline-allowed/> 
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security> 
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="screenshare_applet.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
         name="Red5 ScreenShare"
         main-class='org.redfire.screen.ScreenShare'
         width="500"
         height="440">
        <param name="host" value="localhost"/>
        <param name="app" value="screenshare"/>
        <param name="port" value="1935"/>
        <param name="stream" value="screen_share"/>
        <param name="codec" value="flashsv2"/>
        <param name="framerate" value="15"/>
        <param name="width" value="960"/>
        <param name="height" value="600"/>

     </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Note: I am embedding JNLP for the applet on the page as suggested on this link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/embeddingJNLPFileInWebPage.html

When I run the JApplet in browser, screenshare stream looks blurred as you can see in the following image. However when I run the same JApplet from eclipse the stream is not blurred at all!

[image: blurred screenstream]

Any idea where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with this project, but I can offer an alternative here: https://github.com/Red5/deskshare

Comment: Thanks @PaulGregoire does this support remote control?

Comment: No, it doesnt support remote control.

Comment: Thanks @PaulGregoire Is there any documentation available for it. I am just not very expert in Java.

Comment: I don't know how to set it up. I am using code for Deskshare found here https://github.com/BigMarker/deskshare-public

Comment: The Readme.md in each section show the setup and config options; if you don't understand Java it may be too much to deal with. I assumed from your post that you had a good handle on Java.

Comment: I am from an Android background and I am familiar with Red5. Then I understand maven and ant.

Comment: @PaulGregoire Basically I am not getting how to setup the bbb and Tunnel Servlet because when I go into that it has certain missing packages like com.bigmarker.conference.service.deskshare.common.Dimension
& com.bigmarker.conference.service.deskshare.session.SessionManager.

Comment: Do I need to use https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/tree/master/deskshare/app as the red5 app for this screen share? @PaulGregoire

Comment: The BBB app is not the same; everything you need is in the bigmarker repo, it is just geared for use with BBB; its a replacement for their deskshare app.

Comment: @PaulGregoire and what about the red5 app for publishing the desktop stream OR any default red5 app will work? Also when I go into bbb/StreamControllerServlet.java it has certain missing packages like com.bigmarker.conference.service.deskshare.common.Dimension & com.bigmarker.conference.service.deskshare.session.SessionManager. Finally can I convert this to applet since its web start right now?

Comment: Its not an out-of-the-box solution; it would seem that it is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @PaulGregoire Question: Can I use org.red5.server.session.SessionManager instead of com.bigmarker.conference.service.deskshare.session.SessionManager? Since the latter was not found in source. I am very thankful to you on explaining me all things.

Comment: I assume they are similar, look at what is being saved / recalled and for Dimension it is just simple info width and height I think.

Comment: @PaulGregoire The signature for createSession method is different than red5 SessionManager class. By any chance can you push source code for com.bigmarker.conference.service.deskshare.session package on the GitHub repo?

Comment: @PaulGregoire any news on my previous comment regarding com.bigmarker.conference.service.deskshare.session package source code as that is not available on GitHub repo for deskshare?

Comment: Sorry but I cannot share their source without authorization; what you see in the public repo is all that is currently allowed.

Comment: @PaulGregoire I understand that. Do you have a .jar or a compiled version of this package? Because otherwise how can I build bbb/StreamControllerServlet.java as it requires com.bigmarker.conference.service.deskshare.session package. See this image https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uvxlc5cp0lmk6h/missing-package.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the red5-screenshare applet fixed after changing the screen width and height parameter to sWidth and sHeight. Because applet was considering its canvas width and height as screen dimensions resulting in blurred screen capturing.

Answer (score 1):

The SessionManager in BBB is now provided in scala, so you can see the signature of the methods [here](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/blob/master/deskshare/app/src/main/scala/org/bigbluebutton/deskshare/server/sessions/SessionManagerSVC.scala) and create a java class which implements them. Then change the import to your class and it will build.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I figured it out.